# Python Selenium: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bungol.ca/')
driver.set_window_size(width=1300, height=750)
time.sleep(1)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/button[@type="submit" and text()="Search"]'))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'activeListings'))).click() #sold
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'useDateRange'))).click()

# I found that I had to click the start date every time I wanted to interact with
# anything related to the date selection div/table

#START DATE CALENDAR SELECT

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
start_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//select[@class="pika-select pika-select-year"]'))
start_year.select_by_visible_text('2015')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
start_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pika-select-month"))
start_month.select_by_visible_text("January")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@data-day="1"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

#END DATE CALENDAR SELECT

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
end_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pika-select-year"))
end_year.select_by_visible_text('2015')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
end_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pika-select-month"))
end_month.select_by_visible_text('December')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@data-day="31"]').click()
```

Website reference: https://www.bungol.ca/map/?

I am having trouble clicking the end date on the side bar. The strange thing is, if I run the code by selecting the end date first then start date, the end date would be selected but the start date would not be selected. So I can only select one date in the same script.

When I try to select both dates, I get the error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64)

I did try to do delay as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some places with wrong `xPath`, I have fixed them all:

```
driver.get('https://www.bungol.ca/')
driver.set_window_size(width=1300, height=750)
time.sleep(1)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/button[@type="submit" and text()="Search"]'))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'activeListings'))).click() #sold
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'useDateRange'))).click()

# I found that I had to click the start date every time I wanted to interact with
# anything related to the date selection div/table

#START DATE CALENDAR SELECT

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
start_year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//select[@class="pika-select pika-select-year"]'))
start_year.select_by_visible_text('2015')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
start_month = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".pika-select-month"))
start_month.select_by_visible_text("January")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeStart" and @name="soldDateStart"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@data-day="1"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

#END DATE CALENDAR SELECT

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
end_year = Select(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pika-select-year")[1]) # here
end_year.select_by_visible_text('2015')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
end_month = Select(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pika-select-month")[1]) # here
end_month.select_by_visible_text("December")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="dateRangeEnd" and @name="soldDateEnd"]').click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@data-day="31"]')[1].click() # here

print("END")
```

The problem was that you are used the same selectors for both of calendars. And that means when you tried to interact with second calendar you actually interacted still with the first one. `driver.find_elements` and `[1]` solved the problem